# React Native Gesture Handler Not Working On Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am using react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-reanimated package to animate a View in react native. The scale of the view should increase on tap and the backgroundColor should change to red on tap. Everything works fine when I launch the app on the web but on android I
get no feedback.  I used snack to text my code on my device and that worked on my android device but when I run  the project with expo-start on my laptop the gesture handling doesn't work at all. Any help will be much appreciated . The project is expo managed.

I am using react-native-reanimated version  "~2.3.1", react-native-gesture-handler version "2.1.0";

//MY APP.JS FILE

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Animated,{useAnimatedGestureHandler, useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue} from "react-native-reanimated";
import {  TapGestureHandler } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export default function App() {

  const pressed= useSharedValue(false);

  const gestureEvent= useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart:()=>{
     
     pressed.value=true
    },
    onActive:(e)=>{
      pressed.value=true;
    },
    onEnd:()=>{
      pressed.value=false;
    }
  });

  const animationStyle=useAnimatedStyle(()=>{
    return {
      transform:[{scale:pressed.value?1.3:1}],
      backgroundColor:pressed.value?"red":"yellow"
    }
  })



  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TapGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureEvent}  >
        <Animated.View style={[styles.view,animationStyle]}></Animated.View>
      </TapGestureHandler>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  view:{
    backgroundColor:"blue",
    width:100,
    height:100,
    borderRadius:20,
  }
});
```

// BABEL CONFIG.JS

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
  };
};
```

The scale of the view should increase on tap and the backgroundColor should change to red on tap. Everything works fine when I launch the app on the web but on android I
get no feedback.  I used snack to text my code on my device and that worked on my android device but when I run  the project with expo-start on my laptop the gesture handling doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 21):

Is `<GestureHandlerRootView>` somewhere in your hierarchy? I've noticed this is not required in iOS, but is in Android. See their [Docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/installation/).

Comment: This fixes the issue for me. Any idea why the project of wcandillon (see https://github.com/wcandillon/can-it-be-done-in-react-native/tree/master/playground/src/Pinch) works on android without `GestureHandlerRootView / gestureHandlerRootHOC`?

Comment: I've already used this but it still isn't working for me

Answer (score 12):

Wrap your entire app with

```js
<GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>

</GestureHandlerRootView>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The Flex: 1 is important, without it your app won't be able to detect gestures on android.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I had to do `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler` first, since that is where `<<GestureHandlerRootView>` should be imported from. And then I had to add this in the top: `import {GestureHandlerRootView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';` ... AND THEN it started working, without errors. PHEW!!!