# Expo/React native application crash on physical device trough APK installation

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk, eas

I'm currently building a React Native application with Expo. When running the application with the local server and the Expo Go application I dont have any issue. App run well on IOS and Android devices. 
Now I'm trying to build an APK of the application for test purposes inside my team. To build it I followed [this documentation to use eas](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/).

Now the apk install on the Android device but if I click on any button (they all trigger a `navigate` action onPress) the app crash instantly. I was using `TouchableOpacity` and I changed everyone of them to `Pressable` so the probleme does not come from the button. I'm wondering if i could come from the navigation system ?

Here is the dependencies of my project :

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.6",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "expo": "~47.0.13",
    "expo-camera": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.0.1",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Sorry but we can not really help you on a crash if you don't provide more details like a stack trace or other error details. Check `adb logcat` for errors while the app crashes and include them in your question (edit it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71618989/react-native-gesture-handler-not-working-on-android) 
I forgot a `GestureHandlerRootView` at the root of my application .